# Wrap adjacent elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to wrap adjacent elements with the same class in a div using `jQuery`. So far I'm using `.wrapAll` function to wrap elements with the same class in a div.

HTML:

```
<a class="image"></a>
<a class="image"></a>
<a class="image"></a>
<p>Some text</p>
<a class="image"></a>
<a class="image"></a>
```

Script:

```
$( "a.image" ).wrapAll( "<div class='gallery'></div>" );
```

Output:

```
<div class='gallery'>
    <a class="image"></a>
    <a class="image"></a>
    <a class="image"></a>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <a class="image"></a>
    <a class="image"></a>
</div>
```

However I need to wrap the **adjacent** elements with 'image' class in **separate divs** with 'galley' class. So the output needs to look like this:

```
<div class='gallery'>
    <a class="image"></a>
    <a class="image"></a>
    <a class="image"></a>
</div>
<p>Some text</p>
<div class='gallery'>
    <a class="image"></a>
    <a class="image"></a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You get the non adjacent images (the first and the one just after the `p`) by using `.not` function.
2. For each of them you collect the adjacent image by using (`.nextUntil` and `andSelf`).
3. Finally you wrap them all using `.wrapAll`

```js
$('.image').not('.image+.image').each(function(){
  $(this).nextUntil(':not(.image)').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="gallery" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="image">1</a>
<a class="image">2</a>
<a class="image">3</a>
<p>Some text</p>
<a class="image">4</a>
<a class="image">5</a>
```

http://jsbin.com/gonino/edit?html,js

**Update** This is the result of the snippet.

[image]